# Program recovered from panic does not exit as expected

Tags: go

Per my understanding, when a panic is recovered, I expected the program to exit and exhibit normal behaviour but it does not. Am I right to expect the last line to print "End of program"?
it won't be printed in case of runtime error, is it?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Cause of panic ==>>, %q\n", r)
        }
    }()
    f(3)
    fmt.Println("End of program")
}

func f(x int) {
    fmt.Printf("f(%d) is called.\n", x) //panic triggered when x==0
    // defer called in reverse order in case of panic
    defer fmt.Printf("defer %d\n", x+0/x)

    f(x-1)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Go spec has a good description of what happens on [panic / recover](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics). A panic terminates the current function and all callers until the program exits. On the way, it executes all deferred functions. If one of those functions has a `recover()` and exits cleanly, the panic propagation is stopped.

In your case, panic terminates functions in this order: `f(0)`, `f(1)`, `f(2)`, `f(3)`, `main()`, running each function's deferred functions.

Your deferred function with `recover()` is located in `main()`. This means that **`main()` is interrupted by the panic before it reaches the print statement, and the deferred function is called after**.

If you want to catch the panic, recover, and continue on in main, you would need to add an intermediate function. eg:

```golang
func main() {
    handlePanic(3)
    fmt.Println("End of program")
}

func handlePanic(x int) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Cause of panic ==>>, %q\n", r)
        }
    }()
    f(x)
}

func f(x int) {
    fmt.Printf("f(%d) is called.\n", x) //panic triggered when x==0
    // defer called in reverse order in case of panic
    defer fmt.Printf("defer %d\n", x+0/x)

    f(x-1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"End of program" will not be printed.

When a panic is detected, the function causing the panic immediately returns, as well as the function calling that function, etc. all the way to the function that calls `recover`. When that function returns and recovers, the program then continues as if no panic has happened.

In your case, `main` is the function that recovers. The panic is triggered at `f(3)` call, and the recovery takes place after main returns, bypassing the println.