# Continue execution after recovered panic without knowing which function might panic

Tags: go, recover, panic

I was referred to this question: [Program recovered from panic does not exit as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63867365/program-recovered-from-panic-does-not-exit-as-expected)
It works fine but it relies on knowing where the panic occurs in order to place the deferred function.
My code is as follows.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    defer recoverPanic()
    f1()
    f2()
    f3()
}

func f1() {
    fmt.Println("f1")
}

func f2() {
    defer f3() //<--- don't want to defer f3 here because I might not know f2 will panic, panic could occuer elsewhere
    fmt.Println("f2")
    panic("f2")
}

func f3() {
    fmt.Println("f3")
}

func recoverPanic() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Cause of panic ==>> %q\n", r)
    }
}
```

Having the deferred function call f3() in the panicking function works, output below.

```
f1
f2
f3
Cause of panic ==>> "f2"
```

What if you have an application where you don't know where a panic occurs, do I need to put a defer in every function that might panic?
Commenting out the `defer f3()` gives me the following output.

```
f1
f2
Cause of panic ==>> "f2"
```

f3 never runs.

My question is how to continue execution of the program without having a deferred function call in every function that **might** panic?

Answer (score 5):

You can't resume function execution after a panic. Panic is used when the current line of execution **cannot continue correctly**. Arbitrarily resuming execution after a panic (if it were possible) is begging immediately for another panic, because the state is already incorrect and just blazing ahead won't fix that.

For example, let's say a function panics when it tries to read out of bounds on a slice. How can it continue? What would it even mean to continue? Should it just read the out of bounds memory location and get garbage data? Continue with a zero value? Take a different value from the slice?

You must handle error cases; either by *explicitly* recovering, or preemptively checking / correcting conditions that will result in panic. At least in the standard library, functions that may spur a panic will say so in their documentation with an explanation of which conditions will result in panic.

If you commonly need to safely call *void* functions and recover from any panics, you can make a simple wrapper function for that.

```golang
func try(f func()) {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("caught panic:", err)
        }
    }()
    f()
}
```

Then

```golang
func main() {
    try(f1)
    try(f2)
    try(f3)
}
```

Comment: The `try` func could be expanded to return an `error` so the caller knows how successful it was. Wrapping a "panic" error so the caller could tell how severe the error was.